# Skip policies from all controller actions of pundit in existing project rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using existing rails application, where we currently use devise for authentication and Pundit for authorization. My requirement is to skip all policies scope authorization for all action in this existing rails application. How Can I do this?

I have tried below code but not worked:-

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_user!, :set_default_timezone#, :modify_search_params
  before_action :set_current_user
  skip_after_action :verify_policy_scoped
  #.....
end
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Pundit provides `skip_authorization` to skip his authorization. Executing it before all actions of the controller will make it work for your requirement.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # ...
  before_action :skip_all_authorization

 private 
 def skip_all_authorization
   skip_authorization
 end
# ...
end
```

Comment: This won't work for actions authorized with a `policy_scope`. Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip both action authorization with an object (which are called by using `authorize(object)` and with a policy scope (called with `policy_scope`).

You can skip the hooks on your base class:

```
skip_after_action :verify_policy_scoped
skip_after_action :verify_authorized
```

Or just add another hook to skip them on your controller (my preferred approach)

```
after_action :skip_all_authorization

private

def skip_all_authorization
 skip_policy_scope
 skip_authorization 
end
```

But by the way, you shouldn't need this unless you're [ensuring the policy is called by adding the appropriate hooks](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#ensuring-policies-and-scopes-are-used).